# Removing outliers using the get_outlier function (R studio: repeated measures ANOVA)?

Tags: r, anova, outliers, assumptions

0

I am trying to remove outliers from my dataset:

`Outliers <- Overallproportionofcorrecttrials %>% 
    group_by(Condition,Distancetotarget) %>% 
    identify_outliers(Proportionofcorrecttrials)`

```
Condition Distancetotarget Proportionofcorrecttrials ID      is.outlier is.extreme
      <dbl>            <dbl>               <dbl> <chr>          <lgl>      <lgl>     
1         0            320.                    0.6 P_200220145557 TRUE       FALSE 
2         2             63.2                  0.8 P_200220145557 TRUE      FALSE 
3         2             94.8                   0.8 P_200220145557 TRUE       FALSE
4         2            142.                  1   P_200220145557 TRUE  TRUE
5         2            213 .                 1   P_200220145557 TRUE FALSE
6         2            320                   0.4 P_200217101213 TRUE TRUE    
7         2            320                   0.2 P_200219163622 TRUE FALSE     
8 .       2 .          320 .                 0.4 P_200220145557 TRUE FALSE
```

I get the output above.

Am I right in removing all the datapoints above which correspond to OUTLIER = TRUE as a next step, in order to make the analysis as accurate/truthful as possible?

Or do I only remove the datapoints for EXTREME=TRUE?

When I remove these outliers, both of my within subjects variables become significant, rather than only one prior to removal (two-way repeated measures ANOVA).

Additionally, when I check for outliers after I remove the outliers above, it gives me this output:

```
Condition Distancetotarget Proportionofcorrecttrials ID             is.outlier is.extreme
      <dbl>            <dbl>                     <dbl> <chr>          <lgl>      <lgl>     
1         2             213.                       0.4 P_200217101213 TRUE       FALSE     
2         2             213.                       0.4 P_200224092247 TRUE       FALSE     
3         2             213.                       0.4 P_200225171612 TRUE       FALSE
```

And thus it seems like a never-ending loop?

Could anyone give a helping hand?

Comment: Why are you removing outliers at all?

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica I guess my question is whether I need to: I've seen in the literature "there were no significant outliers" etc where authors have used similar repeated-measures ANOVA designs. But on looking at boxplots of the data, the outliers do not seem worrying, as there are many outlying points that cluster around the same value of the dependent variable.

Comment: What you need to do depends on many factors including what sort of analysis you are doing, why the outliers are in there, etc. Please give us details of your study (dependent variable, independent variables, research questions etc).

Comment: @PeterFlom-ReinstateMonica, Human Path integration using solely self-motion cues derived from optic flow (using VR headset). DV: the proportion of correct trials (the number of trials across the experiment where a subject correctly stops in target zone). Within-sj factors; distance: the distance of the trajectory to the target changes throughout the experiment and gain: the maximal velocity the subject can travel at changes on each trial. Humans show inter-individual differences in PI ability, and certain subjects may be better navigators: +VR experience/differing anatomy/environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't know the specific cause of the infinite loop you're observing without specific information about how your function `identify_outliers()` is labeling cases as outliers, but common approaches like removing cases above or below 3 standard deviations from the mean, or outside of 1.5 * IQR, could give you the same behavior you're observing if you're recalculating the criteria for labeling an outlier on each successive iteration.

The code below illustrates this with random data drawn from a normal distribution, and using 3 standard deviations from mean as criteria to define outliers:

```
# make toy data
x <- rnorm(10000)

# remove outliers above or below 3 standard deviations from mean
remove_outliers_1 <- 
  x[x > (mean(x) - 3*sd(x)) & 
    x < (mean(x) + 3*sd(x))]
# proportion removed
length(remove_outliers_1) / length(x)

# if you use same mean and sd as x, you'll find no additional outliers in second pass
remove_outliers_2 <- 
  remove_outliers_1[remove_outliers_1 > (mean(x) - 3*sd(x)) & 
                    remove_outliers_1 < (mean(x) + 3*sd(x))]
# proportion removed
length(remove_outliers_2) / length(x)

# if you recalculate mean and standard deviation based on new data, you'll have more outliers!
remove_outliers_3 <- 
  remove_outliers_1[remove_outliers_1 > (mean(remove_outliers_1) - 3*sd(remove_outliers_1)) & 
                    remove_outliers_1 < (mean(remove_outliers_1) + 3*sd(remove_outliers_1))]
# proportion removed
length(remove_outliers_3) / length(remove_outliers_1)
```

To avoid the infinite loop, then, if your outlier definition uses a statistic drawn from your data, then you should only remove outliers once; if your criteria are absolute, then you won't observe this kind of recursive behavior, as you'll have removed all cases meeting the criteria in your first pass.

The decision to remove outliers really depends on your study parameters and, most important, your planned methodology for analyzing data. If you're planning any kind of parametric analysis, for instance, removing outliers is often a best practice, because they can skew your mean and standard deviation.